# WebView NavigateToString Local file image

Tags: c#, webview, win-universal-app

I am working on a Windows Universal application that I am converting from a Windows Phone Silverlight app.  In my application I use a webview to display content via the ***WebView.NavigateToString()*** method.  The string that I navigate to references images that the app downloads and stores in ***ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder***.

In my silverlight app, I was able to do  however in my universal app, this does not seem to work anymore.  I say someone mention that you could use a url in the form: ***$"ms-appdata:///{localPath}"*** however that does not seem to be working either.

Is there any way for me to load these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebView and resources are a strange thing when using NavigateToString.

I solved it by putting the images into the string directly:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS....
```

Look for [Data Uri Scheme](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was really hoping I wouldn't have to go this route.  However if that is the only way to load the images, I guess I will have to do it..